# Setting decimal on database but still only reads whole numbers

Tags: php, html, database, decimal

I have this form which updates the records in the database. I'm supposed to input decimal numbers, it does its job and updates the database. The problem is that it only reads whole numbers.

Example:

2.35 (updated value becomes 2)

I also did set the type of sickleave and vacationleave to decimal in my database. What might be the problem? Am I doing it wrong?

Here's my code:

```html
<?php
/*
Allows the user to both create new records and edit existing records
*/

// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");

// creates the new/edit record form
// since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
function renderForm($fullname = '', $username ='', $error = '', $id = '', $email = '', $address = '', $contact = '', $gender = '', $password = '', $user_levels = '', $date = '', $picture = '', $sickleave = '', $vacationleave = '')
{ ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">

<style> 

 body {
  background-image: url("img/wood2.jpg");
 }
 
 html {
  font-family: Questrial;
 }
 
 .main > div {
  position: center;
 }

 .register {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 7px solid #285f9f;
   border-radius: 10px;
   font-family: Questrial;
   color: #444;
   background-color: #F0F0F0;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 #000000;
 }
 .register h3 {
   margin: 0 15px 20px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #285f9f;
   padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
   font-size: 1.1em;
 }
 .register div {
   margin: 0 0 15px 0;
   border: none;
 }
 .register label {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 25%;
   text-align: right;
   margin: 10px;
 }
 .register input[type=text], .register input[type=password] {
   width: 65%;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
 }
 .register input[type=text]:focus, .register input[type=password]:focus {
   background: #FFFFFF;
 }
 .register .button {
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: Questrial;
   border-radius: 8px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #285f9f;
   background: #285f9f;
  
 }
 .register .button:hover {
   background: #51DB1C;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#51DB1C, #6BA061);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#51DB1C, #6BA061);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#51DB1C, #6BA061);
   background: linear-gradient(#51db1c, #6ba061);
 }
 .register .sep {
   border: 1px solid #72B372;
   position: relative;
   margin: 35px 20px;
 }
 .register .or {
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   left: 50%;
   background: #F0F0F0;
   text-align: center;
   margin: -10px 0 0 -25px;
   line-height: 20px;
 }
 .register .connect {
   width: 400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
 }
 
</style>

<title> <?php if ($id != '') { echo "Edit Record"; } else { echo "New Record"; } ?> </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

</head>
<body>

 <?php if ($error != '') {
 echo "<div style='padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red'>" . $error
 . "</div>";
 } ?>

<div class="main">
 <div class="one">
    <div class="register">
      <center><h3>Edit Account #</h3></center>
      <form action="" method="post">
  <div>
          <label>ID</label>
    <?php if ($id != '') { ?>
    <?php echo $id;?>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Fullname</label>
          <input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname;?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Contact</label>
          <input type="text" name="contact" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Gender</label>
          <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>User Levels</label>
          <input type="text" name="user_levels" value="<?php echo $user_levels; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Picture</label>
          <?php echo $picture; ?>
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Sick Leave</label>
          <input type="text" name="sickleave" value="<?php echo $sickleave; ?>">
        </div>
  <div>
          <label>Vacation Leave</label>
          <input type="text" name="vacationleave" value="<?php echo $vacationleave; ?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button" />
    <a href="view.php"><input type="button" value="View Records" class="button" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>

<?php }

/* EDIT RECORD */
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
// get variables from the URL/form
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $fullname = htmlentities($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $address = htmlentities($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $contact = htmlentities($_POST['contact'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $gender = htmlentities($_POST['gender'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $user_levels = htmlentities($_POST['user_levels'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $date = htmlentities($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $picture = htmlentities($_POST['picture'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $sickleave = htmlentities($_POST['sickleave'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $vacationleave = htmlentities($_POST['vacationleave'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($fullname == '' || $username == '' || $email == '' || $address == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
 renderForm($fullname, $username, $error, $id, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave);
}
else
{
// if everything is fine, update the record in the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE signup_and_login_users_table SET fullname = ?, username = ?, email = ?,
address = ?,
contact = ?,
gender = ?,
password = ?,
user_levels = ?,
date = ?,
picture = ?,
sickleave = ?,
vacationleave = ?
WHERE id = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssiii", $fullname, $username, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave, $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
// show an error message if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirect the user once the form is updated
header("Location: view.php");
}
}
// if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
else
{
echo "Error!";
}
}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
else
{
// make sure the 'id' value is valid
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
// get 'id' from URL
 $id = $_GET['id'];

// get the recod from the database
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM signup_and_login_users_table WHERE id=?"))
{
 $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
 $stmt->execute();

 $stmt->bind_result($id, $fullname, $username, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave);
 $stmt->fetch();

// show the form
renderForm($fullname, $username, NULL, $id, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave);

$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
 echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
}
}
// if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view.php page
else
{
 header("Location: view.php");
}
}
}



/*

NEW RECORD

*/
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
// if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
 $fullname = htmlentities($_POST['fullname'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $address = htmlentities($_POST['address'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $contact = htmlentities($_POST['contact'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $gender = htmlentities($_POST['gender'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $user_levels = htmlentities($_POST['user_levels'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $date = htmlentities($_POST['date'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $picture = htmlentities($_POST['picture'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $sickleave = htmlentities($_POST['sickleave'], ENT_QUOTES);
 $vacationleave = htmlentities($_POST['vacationleave'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($fullname == '' || $username == '' || $email == '' || $address == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($fullname, $username, $error, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT signup_and_login_users_table (fullname, username, email, address, contact, gender, password, user_levels, date, picture, sickleave, vacationleave) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssiii", $fullname, $username, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}

}
// if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
else
{
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[image: Table Schema]

Comment: Can try to show only relevant code please?

Comment: The table schema would be very useful here...

Comment: @ThoriumBR added the table schema

Comment: By using `DECIMAL(11,0)` you say you want 0 decimals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the numbers as `integers` by using `i`, so it floors them. Try binding the doubles with `d` so it keeps the decimals:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssddi", $fullname, $username, $email, $address, $contact, $gender, $password, $user_levels, $date, $picture, $sickleave, $vacationleave, $id);
```

Also, you have `DECIMAL(11, 0)` as the datatype. The second number being 0 means you'll have 0 decimals. Try setting `sickleave` and `vacationleave` to `DECIMAL(11, 2)` to store 2 decimals.

- [`bind_param()` reference](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`DECIMAL()` reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Comment: Didn't work :( should I change my database type to double too?

Comment: Add the table schema to the original post so we can see it.

Comment: added the table schema

Comment: You are using `DECIMAL(11, 0)`, which means it'll store 0 decimals. Try with `DECIMAL(11, 2)`

Comment: It doesn't change, not sure why... @ishegg

Comment: What do you mean? You can't change the datatype, or you changed and it still won't work? Did you check that `$sickleave` is indeed a float right before binding it?

Comment: I can't change the datatype. Everthing's fine

Comment: What did you try? Use `ALTER TABLE signup_and_login_users_table MODIFY COLUMN sickleave DECIMAL(11,2)`. I think that's definitely your problem, you have explicitly declared that the field won't store decimals.

Comment: I worked! So I probably should've defined it manualy. I'm using phpmyadmin btw.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it! Try to read the references I linked so you make this a great learning experience :)